# Highchart redraw is throwing error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined(…)

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I' trying to redraw all my Highchart as following:

```
Highcharts.charts.map(function(o){
        o.destroy();
        o.redraw();
});
```

But it is throwing following error:

```
highcharts.src.js:12224 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined(…)
```

After navigating I found it unable to find series in chart:
[image: Chart error]
I have some pie and bar chart in my page.

Comment: `series` is apparently not defined. Can you find out where it is defined, and if it's through an external JSON, you will probably have to check to see if your variables correspond with the format that highcharts expects.

Comment: But my chart id rendering fine.

Comment: Even after the redraw?

Comment: No, after redraw it doesn't paint some pie and bar

Comment: Precisely why the data series given to the redraw api doesn't match up to what is expected

Answer (score 4):

As per highcharts documentation http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/Chart.destroy, chart.destroy() flushes chart from memory and container is ready for new chart. So chart.redraw() immediately after chart.destroy() refers to null. Don't use chart.destroy() try updating charts with some values and then call chart.redraw() as redraw doesn't work if chart is not changed/dirty.